# Разганичение прав доступа на уровне модели в административной панели Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Вопрос касается только работы в административной панели Django:

Имеются 2 модели Departments (отделы) и Employees (сотрудники)

```
class Departments(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()   


class Employees(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    fk_departments = models.ForeignKey(Departments)
```

Например, имеются несколько отделов: "Отдел № 1" и "Отдел № 2", в первом работает Иванов, во втором Петров.
Если создать пользователя при помощи административной панели Django и дать ему все права на модель Employees (сотрудники) то пользователь по-умолчанию будет видеть полный  список сотрудников из всех отделов:

1. имя: "Иванов", отдел: "Отдел № 1"
2. имя: "Петров", отдел: "Отдел № 2"

Есть ли возможность изменить права пользователя на уровне разграничения прав по отделам в административной панели Django? (т.е. разные пользователи должны видеть сотрудников только из определенных отделов).

Например, в списке сотрудников Пользователь № 1 будет видеть только "Иванова" из "Отдела № 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно решение "костыльное", но я решил проблему, добавив в модуле приложения admin.py следующее:

```
class EmployeesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .... списки отображаемых полей....

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EmployeesAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        # Если текущий пользователь суперюзер возвращаем всё:
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        # Если текущий пользователь принадлежит к группе "Отдел № 1" возвращаем Сотрудников только из "Отдел № 1":
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='Отдел № 1').exists():
            return qs.filter(fk_departments=1)
        # Если текущий пользователь принадлежит к группе "Отдел № 2" возвращаем Сотрудников только из "Отдел № 2":
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='Отдел № 2').exists():
            return qs.filter(fk_departments=2)
```